# static_cast literal 0 to other types in STL

Tags: c++, stl, static-cast

Which type can 0 be cast to? pointers, numeric vars. Any others? Will the following cast be safe?

ps: an excerpt from STL implementation of iterator

```
template <class Iterator>
inline typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type*
distance_type(const Iterator&) {
  return static_cast<typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type*>(0);
}

template <class Iterator>
inline typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type*
value_type(const Iterator&) {
  return static_cast<typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type*>(0);
}
```

Comment: "Safe"?! Does it even compile?

Comment: Well, it will certainly not if `value_type` is chosen accordingly. `0` can be cast to pointers and numerics, that's it.

Comment: Both those casts are to pointers, and pointers can be NULL, so yes.

Comment: @KerrekSB Actually, it's part of the STL.

Comment: @zoujyjs: More precisely: Does the specialization for your own case about which you are worried compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All kinds of pointers including pointer-to-function, pointer-to-member, pointer-to-member-function; arithmetic types; anything with a 1-arg `int` constructor; anything with a 1-arg constructor taking a type that `0` can be implicitly converted to. Probably something else I haven't thought of.

Assuming that `iterator_traits` resolves to `std::iterator_traits`, then `typename iterator_traits<Iterator>::difference_type*` is certainly a pointer-to-object type, except perhaps in a program that has an incorrect specialization of `iterator_traits`. So yes, the cast works.

If you messed up and defined `difference_type` or `value_type` as a reference type, or not a type at all, then you'd have problems with that code.

Comment: `void`, too. I think "arithmetic" plus `void` together are the _fundamental types_.